# Backbone: Fetch before rendering

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backbone.js

I'm trying to add a new item to my backbone collection using:

```
window.bearList.create({ name: "Tina" } );
```

This correctly saves the new item to the server, because afterwards I can see this on the server, which is what I want. (I'm using MongoDB)

```
{"name":"Tina","_id":"53b41d92b7083d0b00000009","__v":0}
```

I have this binding in my bearList ListView:

```
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.collection.bind('add', this.render);
    },
```

The problem is that the code above just adds the following to my collection view until I reload the page.

```
 {"name":"Tina"}
```

I've tried using the model.save() callback, but I still have the same issue.

Like I said, everything looks fine on the server, and the collection has the correction version of 'Tina' once I reload the page.

But for some reason, it is not getting the full model for the ListView's 'render' event. I've tried fetching each model individually on the ListView render method, but this did not work and is bad practice anyway.

Can someone help me out?

Here is my full code for this:

```
window.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    className: 'list-group',

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.collection.bind('add', this.render);
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(" ");
        this.collection.each(function(item){
        var listItemView = new ListItemView({ model: item });
        this.$el.append(listItemView.render().el);
        }, this);
    return this;
    },

});



window.ListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'list-group-item',

    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("change", this.render);
    },

    render:function () {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.$el.html("<a href='#"+ this.model.hashType + "/"+this.model.get('_id')+"' >" + this.model.get('name') + "</a>");
    return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass wait:true.

```
window.bearList.create({ name: "Tina" }, {wait: true} );
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create

> Pass {wait: true} if you'd like to wait for the server before adding
>   the new model to the collection.

Comment: I did see that, it still is not giving me the full model in render function. I'm just getting a server response like this: `{"name":"Tina","message":"Bear created!"}`

Comment: Listen to "sync" instead of add, also be sure that server response contains _id. Per Backbone documentation: as well as a "sync" event, once the server has responded with the successful creation of the model

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just modified my api to return the full JSON instead of just "Bear created". That is working

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the `sync` event since `add` will only add the values you are creating from within backbone. http://backbonejs.org/#Sync

And a tip: use listenTo to use more of Backbone's features.
instead of

```
initialize:function () {
    this.model.bind("change", this.render);
},
```

use:

```
initialize:function () {
    this.listenTo( this.model, "change", this.render );
},
```